# How to validate this data structure with Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

So far not having any luck with Firebase Security rules.

I have this

```
{
    "rules": {
       "users": {
          "$user_id": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $user_id",
            "profile": {
               ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['first_name', 'last_name'])"
            }
         }
      }
    }
}
```

I send data and for the profile and one of them is blank... it lets it write any way. I wind up with data like so...

```
{
  "users" : {
    "simplelogin:25" : {
       "profile" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "last_name" : ""
       }
  },
    "simplelogin:26" : {
      "profile" : {
        "first_name" : "Bob",
        "last_name" : ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help on how to make the above rules work? Cant seem to get it to validate correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your validation rule is:

```
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['first_name', 'last_name'])"
```

So the new data is valid if it has `first_name` and `last_name` properties.

You're sending this object over:

```
"profile" : {
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : ""
}
```

This object has a `first_name` and a `last_name` property, so it is valid according to your rule.

What you seem to *want* is that the properties don't only exist, but also are strings and have a minimum length. If that is indeed your requirement, you can write it into your validation rules:

```
"profile": {
   ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['first_name', 'last_name'])",
   "first_name": {
       ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 10"
   },
   "last_name": {
       ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length >= 10"
   }
}
```

The first `.validate` ensures that a profile has (at least) `first_name` and `last_name` properties. The other `.validate` rules ensure that they are of the correct type and minimum length.

Comment: Thank you Frank - That makes perfect sense!

Comment: One more info for others! We should state `.validate` for all the nodes in `hasChildren`. If not, we will get permission denied error :(

Comment: I sounds like you had a different problem @ChemicalProgrammer. If it persists, it's better to open a new question.